# How to get a value from Pandas DataFrame column with dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a pandas dataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
lead_comments = [{'lead_id':1, 'note_id': 1, 'params': {'text': 'first_comment'}}, {'lead_id':1, 'note_id': 2, 'params': {'text': 'second_comment'}}, {'lead_id':1, 'note_id': 3, 'params': {'text': 'third_comment'}}]
df = pd.DataFrame(lead_comments)
print df
```

Output:

```
   lead_id  note_id   params
0  1        1         {'text': 'first_comment'}
1  1        2         {'text': 'second_comment'}
2  1        3         {'text': 'third_comment'}
```

I`m trying to extract a 'text' value from df['Params'], the result I want looks like:

```
   lead_id  note_id   params
0  1        1         first_comment
1  1        3         second_comment
2  1        3         third_comment
```

i've tried to use `pandas.apply()` like

```
def get_comment_text(x):
    for value in x["params"]["text"]:
        return value

df['comment_text'] = df.apply(get_comment_text, axis=1)
```

but it gave my a wrong output:

```
   lead_id  note_id   params
0  1        1         f
1  1        3         s
2  1        3         t
```

Where did I go wrong and how to get right values? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html):

```
#if dictionaries are strings
#import ast

#df["params"] = df["params"].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df['comment_text'] = df["params"].str.get("text")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `assign` and `str` accessor `__getitem__`:

```
>>> df.assign(params=df['params'].str['text'])
   lead_id  note_id          params
0        1        1   first_comment
1        1        2  second_comment
2        1        3   third_comment
>>>
```

It looks like you are still using Python 2... Switch to Python 3!

If your dataframe dictionaries are string, before the code use:

```
import ast
df["params"] = df["params"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` and `lambda` (*this approach is slower*):

```
>>> df['params'].apply(lambda x: x.get('text'))
0     first_comment
1    second_comment
2     third_comment
Name: params, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
df['params'] = df['params'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Output:

```
  lead_id  note_id          params
0        1        1   first_comment
1        1        2  second_comment
2        1        3   third_comment
```